# MongoDB read preferences Secondary

Tags: mongodb, ycsb

I am just starting to use MongoDB while testing it with YCSB and I have a couple of questions about read preferences and its implementation.

I have setup 1 Primary and 2 Secondary nodes, and set reading preferences on YCSB java client like this `mongo.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondary());`

**1.** Why if I point YCSB to connect to primary node it still can perform read operations without generating error message? Also I checked the logs and I can see that Primary is the node that served these requests.

**2** How do clients know about Secondary nodes in a production environment?  Where do you connect clients by default? Do all the clients go to Primary, retrieve list of Secondaries and then reconnect to secondaries to perform reads ?

**3** By browsing source code I have found that logic of selecting appropriate replica based on preferences is done in `replica_set_monitor.cpp` Although it is not yet clear to me where this code is executed, is it on Primary, Secondary or client?

Thank you

Comment: Mongodb is not a key value store so not sure why ou have tagged this with such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application connects to any active replica member it will issue a internal type of `rs.status()` which is infact a `isMaster` command (http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/connect-driver-to-replica-set/) and caches the response of that for a specific time until deemed fit to refresh that information, in fact in the c++ driver even tells you the class that will hold the cache: http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/current/classmongo_1_1_replica_set_monitor.html

> Holds state about a replica set and provides a means to refresh the local view.

There are number of ways that the application can connect to a set to understand, the most common way is by providing a seed list into the connection string within your application code to the driver, that way it can connect to any member and ask: "What is there here?"

Comment: Is it correct to assume that other drivers such as Java, have their own version of replica_set_monitor, and should follow the same logic of choosing replicas and refreshing that cache?

Comment: @2di indeed, every driver I know of has their own version of it.

Answer (score 2):

When your application connects only to the primary, it doesn't learn about any secondaries. `ReadPreference.secondary()` is just a preference, not a mandate. When the application doesn't know that a secondary exists, it will read from the primary.

To make your application aware of the secondaries, you need to use the class [`DBClientReplicaSet`](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_replica_set.html) instead of `DBClientConnection` which takes an `std::vector` of hosts as a constructor argument. This array should include all members of the set.

When you would prefer to have the application unaware of the replica-set members, you could set up a sharded cluster (which might consist of only a single shard) and connect to the router. The mongos process will then handle the replica-set abstraction.